# Python Programming Using multiple functions

Tags: python

Hey im new to python and my teacher wants us to create a function with multiple functions.
Here is what my program looks like

```
def main():
    carpetyards = float(input("Enter amount of yards the carpet is"))
    carpetcost = 5.50 * carpetyards
    fee = carpetcost + 25.00
    tax = .06 * fee
    totalcost = fee + tax  
results() 

def results():
    print()
    print('carpetyards    :' , format (carpetyards))
    print('carpetcost     :' , format (carpetcost, '9,.2f'))
    print('fee            :' , format (fee,        '9,.2f'))
    print('tax            :' , format (tax,        '9,.2f'))
    print('totalcost      :' , format (totalcost,  '9,.2f'))   

main()
```

I get either nameerror or results is not defined error. Can someone please help?

Comment: You're calling it too early, put the function call after the function's definition.

Comment: Ask your teacher about variable scope. Also, indent `results()`.

Comment: Oops sorry create a program with multiple functions

Comment: Ok I tried that and its asks the question but then nothing happens

Comment: Ok and now I just changed it again and got this: print('carpetyards    :' , format (carpetyards))
NameError: global name 'carpetyards' is not defined

Comment: Ok it did actually work this time. Just to be sure here is what my teacher asks in the assignment. You may get the information from the user and do the calculations in main, but all printing must be done in a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

The line at the end of `main()` (`results()`) is not indented, so it the program does this:

1. Define `main()`
2. Run `results()`
3. Define `results()`
4. Run `main()`

As you can see, there will be several errors, because you are not only running `results()` before it is defined, but the variables used in `results()` (which are set in `main()`) are out of its scope (variables set in `main()` only work inside `main()` unless you make them global).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `results` inside the `main` function for this to work,

```
def main():
   carpetyards = float(input("Enter amount of yards the carpet is"))
   carpetcost = 5.50 * carpetyards
   fee = carpetcost + 25.00
   tax = .06 * fee
   totalcost = fee + tax  

   # 'main' function scope
   def results():
     print()
     print('carpetyards    :' , format (carpetyards))
     print('carpetcost     :' , format (carpetcost, '9,.2f'))
     print('fee            :' , format (fee,        '9,.2f'))
     print('tax            :' , format (tax,        '9,.2f'))
     print('totalcost      :' , format (totalcost,  '9,.2f'))   

   results() 

# outer scope
main()
```

You could further define other functions inside `main` as long as you properly indent them.

Comment: I disagree.  You *can* define `results` inside `main`, but you don't *need* to.  `results` can be defined outside `main`, it just needs to be defined before it is used.